# Is there a way to authenticate heroku HTTP Post deploy hooks?

Tags: deployment, heroku

Heroku lets you ping a URL after deploying an application:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-hooks#http-post-hook

However, I see no mention of these requests being signed or otherwise authenticated.

Is there any way to authenticate these, beyond using an obscure url?

-Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can and should use HTTP Basic Auth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Will. How is basic auth more secure than an obscure url?

Comment: The passwords part of basic auth generally stays out of places like logs